# Navigation Controller popToRootController() followed by pushing controllers UI bug

Tags: ios, swift

In my app I'm currently calling navigationController.popToRootController() followed by immediately pushing a few controllers onto the stack, but it's causing a weird UI bug. Instead of appearing from the left side, the new controller being presented appears from bottom up, and the weird thing is the navigation bar at the top of the screen is completely gone. Can't navigate back, can't interact with any of the navigation items ... just gone. Wondering if it has to do with popping to the root controller then immediately trying to push new controllers that could cause this weird bug. Hope someone has an insight into this. Thanks!

fileList is a navigation controller

```
fileList.popToRootController()
fileList.clearList()
var isRoot = true
for file in (deepLinkFolder?.fileList)! {
    // push file controller onto navigation controller (fileList)
}
```

Comment: Please post relevant code (as text) in your question.

Comment: added relevant code, extrapolated the relevant functionality, the code goes through many loops and turns

Comment: I wouldn’t do that. I would just modify the `viewControllers` array to add the controllers. You could also try a `dispatchAsync` of your push so that it occurs on the next run loop iteration

Comment: Are you pushing the new controllers on with the animated property set to true?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to alter the viewControllers like this pop followed by a push it's better to re set the `viewControllers` property like this , the glitch may be because both the pop and the push have animated setted to true so interfering happens

```
self.navigationController?.viewControllers = []
```

or with animation

```
self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([],animated:true)
```

Comment: If I set the array to nil that pops even the root off though, which isn't what I'm going for. popToRootController() should leave the root on the array no?

Comment: the root is at index 0 , create an array hold only the viewController at 0 index , append the other VCS you want to push to it then set this new array to **setViewControllers**