# Popping multiple controllers off navigation controller nil?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

```
for _ in 2...numNavControllers {
    let vc = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
    print("\(String(describing: vc))")
}
```

I'm trying to pop off multiple view controllers, and what's happening is the first iteration of the loop, it will successfully pop the top view controller, but every iteration afterwards the view controller popped off is nil. What's going on? There are multiple view controllers (at least 4), and I've confirmed that with print statements.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in a loop? Why not use `popToRootViewController` or `popToViewController` depending on what you need?

Comment: getting weird bugs in my app with using those functions, trying to pop to the root followed by immediately pushing new controllers causes weird UI bug, where the new controllers appear in a new screen that comes from the bottom of the screen (instead of left to right as is the usual animation), and then new screen is missing the entire navigation bar ...

Comment: So this is related to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50730047/navigation-controller-poptorootcontroller-followed-by-pushing-controllers-ui-b).

Comment: well I'm approaching it from a different angle, was wondering if anyone could enlighten me on why multiple pop calls return nil

Comment: you are also setting animated: true, so it takes a while to complete first pop. but you are not waiting to pop the next one. you cannot pop second one while poping out first one. and as per your comment below you can use `popToRootViewController ` and push relevant VCs without animating. (you may need to use separate threads using DispatchQueue)

Comment: If you're trying to pop some controllers and push others at the same time then you should create an array of whatever final view controllers you want and then use the `setViewControllers` function

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead of using a for loop:

```
var numberOfPops: Int = 3
let viewControllers: [UIViewController] = self.navigationController!.viewControllers as [UIViewController]
self.navigationController!.popToViewController(viewControllers[viewControllers.count - numberOfPops], animated: true)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion! The problem I've been trying to deal with is the following: I want to pop off all the view controllers up to the root, and then immediately push a few view controllers onto the stack (basically the user clicks a link to a specific folder, and I want to navigate to that folder - hence going up to the root then pushing the correct path of controllers). However, when I do it as you suggest, it will pop the controller to the root but as I push the new controllers onto the stack, it creates an entirely new screen from the bottom(and the nav bar at the top is missing)

Comment: wondering if it might be a thread issue or race condition, popping to the root followed by immediately pushing new controllers ... causes the new controllers pushed to be placed seemingly on a new controller ...

Comment: @IsaacZhang why not just pass in a pushViewControllers Bool to the "initial" controller. If pushViewControllers == true then push the next controller. If that controllers pushViewControllers == true, do the exact same.